# How to run a gwt maven project in developpent mode in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, gwt, maven

How to run a gwt maven project in developpent mode in eclipse using embedded Jetty ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the maven eclipse plugin m2eclipse and just use target gwt:run